# Serialize hive map column

Tags: dictionary, hive, hiveql

Is there any custom udf or other function available to serialize hive map field, so that it could be used in group by and join condition.

For example, we have a map field:

```
dim_map = {'dim_geo': 'San Francisco', 'dim_country': 'USA'}
```

As want to join two tables on this field.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to JSON string using [brickhouse udf](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse), download sources, compile, add jar file and create function, see [Getting Started](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse#getting-started) instructions:

```
add jar /path/brickhouse-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;  
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION to_json AS 'brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF';

select to_json(dim_map) as dim_map_json
  from...
```

Update:

As @rajnish mentioned in the comment, maps are not ordered and this may cause problem with comparing such maps converted to JSON.

Example of maps:

```
with test_data as (
select map('dim_geo', 'San Francisco', 'dim_country','USA') map1,
       map('dim_country','USA','dim_geo', 'San Francisco') map2

)

select map1, map2, 
       case when map1['dim_geo']     = map2['dim_geo']     
             and map1['dim_country'] = map2['dim_country'] 
            then 'equal'
            else 'not equal' end as compare_maps
from test_data;
```

Result:

```
map1    map2    compare_maps

{"dim_geo":"San Francisco","dim_country":"USA"} {"dim_country":"USA","dim_geo":"San Francisco"} equal
```

Better compare each value like in this example or write your own UDF using HashMap.equals method.

By default, HashMap. equals() method compares two hashmaps by key-value pairs. It means both hashmap instances must have exactly same key-value pairs and both must be of same size. The order of key-value pairs can be different and does not play in role in comparison. [How to compare two hashmaps in Java](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/hashmap/compare-two-hashmaps/)

Comment: Because map is an unordered column, I am worried that, i am worried that json field could have different order of columns . (FYI: If i use cast JSON to str for join operations)

Comment: @rajnish Yes, map is unordered, this can cause problem... JSON is already string

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin for adding more details. In my case, dim_map can contains different (keys,value) pair based on different scenarios. So it is not possible compare values in the query. I think then the best option would be to write some udf.

Comment: I need some kind of `f(dim_map) --> val: string` that generate the json based on some sorted key or value. So that it is consistent, if i am joining two different tables.

Comment: @rajnish write your own or modify brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF